# tkinter Entry to Listbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I'm trying to make a to do list program on Python 3.8. It will take the inputs from the user by the help of

```
def input_():
    label["text"] = inputword.get()

inputword=Entry()
inputword.pack(anchor = "nw", padx = 10, pady = 10)
```

and a button:

```
add_input= Button(text ="Add to List",
                  command = input_,
                  bg = "#ae0000",
                  fg= "white",
                  font=("Calibri", "15", "bold")
           )
add_input.pack(anchor="nw", padx=10)
```

This works but i couldn't add my inputs to list.

```
listbox=Listbox()
listbox.place(x=250,y=250)
listbox.insert(0, add_input or maybe input_)
```

How should i rearrange my code?

Sample picture from my programL [sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM5X1.png)

Comment: Ive added an answer, do let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like:

```
def input_():
    label["text"] = inputword.get() #dont know what this is cuz label is undefined
    listbox.insert(END, inputword.get()) #argument -> (index,string)
```

You can use the `insert()` method of the `Listbox` to insert into the `Listbox`. This will insert each items to the end of the `Listbox`, when you press the button. If you want each item to be on top rather than bottom of the list, then say 0 instead of `END`.

Hope you understood whats going on, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers